# Ограничить количество нажатий на кнопку для всех пользователей

Tags: javascript, html

Серверная часть полностью отсутствует, возможно ли как то реализовать ограничение нажатий на кнопку для всех пользователей на фронте?

Comment: Для всех - нет. Для конкретно каждого - да

Comment: а каким образом ограничить? кто то первый нажал и все?